# App Crashes because of the table view controller initialization

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

My code to initialise the tableView is:

```
convenience override init(style: UITableViewStyle) {
    self.init(style: .Grouped)
    // Custom initialization
    self.title = NSLocalizedString("mdm.agent.common.desktopCentral", comment : "")
}
```

the error is EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the line

```
 self.init(style: .Grouped)
```

Why is this type of initialisation raising that error, but works with objective c? The objective c code is:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization

    self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"mdm.agent.common.desktopCentral", nil);
}
return self;
```

}

Comment: use super init function first in init(style: UITableViewStyle)

Comment: can u code it and let me know what exactly you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call either call the superclasses init method in your constructor, or call a designated initializer in your own class.

In the example Objective-C code you posted there is the line

```
self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

This line is calling the superclasses implementation of `initWithStyle:`.

In your code you are calling `self.init(style: .Grouped)` from within the the same method which leads to infinite recursion. You can fix this two different ways, either call a different designated initializer such as `self.init()`, or remove the `convenience` keyword to make this a designated initializer, which will let you call the superclasses implementation.

You probably want to do the second option, which would look like this:

```
override init(style tableStyle: UITableViewStyle) {
    super.init(style: style) //use the style value passed into the method
    // Custom initialization
    self.title = NSLocalizedString("mdm.agent.common.desktopCentral", comment : "")
}
```

Comment: error : convenience initializer must delegate(with self.init) rather than chaining to a super class initializer(with super.init)

Comment: error : required initialiser (init : coder ) must be provided by subclass of 'UITableViewController'

Comment: I did it the second way

Comment: Yes, the init: coder class must be overridden. It's okay to leave the implementation empty though (just a log statement) if you don't need to support the NSCoding protocol.

Comment: well , now am setting this controller in didfinishlaunching as    let enrolledView = DetailsViewController()
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(enrolledView, animated: true)

Comment: but the error which has newly appeared states that "cannot invoke initialiser for type "DetailsViewController" with no arguments""